# How can I use dictionary with the key is the type of enum?

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums

How can I use the dictionary with the key is the type of enum?
I had program like this:

```
enum A {
   case a1
   case a2
}
var dic = [A:String]()
dic[A.a1] = "a1 is set"
```

I set breakpoint in Xcode, and I saw the key is `a1`, but the value is not captured. How I can solve the problem?

Comment: That should work without problems. What does `print(dic[A.a1])` show?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but this is Swift, don't use semicolons at the end of the lines.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the Xcode debugger to show in what way that "the value is not captured"?

Comment: Please give more context - create a [mcve] and update your question

Comment: @MartinR Shouldn't key has to be hashable? `enum A: String {}` should fix the problem.

Comment: @Desdenova: Any enumeration without associated values *is* Hashable – the above code compiles and runs in Xcode 9.4.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you